# Is there a way to configure the proxy settings using TestNG

Tags: proxy, testng, configure

I want configure the use of proxy server in my tests.
I want to bypass the proxy settings while I run my scripts locally.
Currently since the proxy server is not reachable form the local host I am not able to run my scripts locally. Is there a way I can direct my scripts when to use the proxy settings and when not?

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling us how you run tests (ant, maven, Eclipse, suite file,...).

BTW, you can configure the proxy (

```
System.setProperty("http....",  "...");
```

) depending on your logic in a @BeforeSuite method.